# Cannot infer type arguments for ArrayAdapter<>

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I am still playing around with my calendar, I already nearly managed to integrate the https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView into one of my fragments. There is just one error left, i did some research, others got the problem too for example with ArrayList<>.

**Example code:**

```
final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>
            (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mutableBookings);
```

**The IDE says:**

```
Error:(87, 38) error: cannot infer type arguments for ArrayAdapter<>
```

Note: C:...\Uebersicht.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

**I already tried to recompile, but the result doesn't seem to work**

```
Uebersicht.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
    final ArrayAdapter adapter = 
          new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mutableBookings);


Uebersicht.java:87: error: cannot find symbol 
final ArrayAdapter adapter = 
          new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mutableBookings);    


Uebersicht.java:87: error: package android.R does not exist
    final ArrayAdapter adapter = 
          new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mutableBookings);
```

I can post my full Fragment class too if it's necessary, it must be something with my API and the API the ArrayAdapter is using? Don't forget I am just a beginner, I am trying to do just some stuff all by myself.

Comment: What type is mutableBookings?

Comment: final List<String> mutableBookings = new ArrayList<>();

but changing to ArrayAdapter<String> doesn't work too

Comment: If you define variable as `final ArrayAdapter adapter` - don't use diamond shorthand: `new ArrayAdapter(this, ...);`

Comment: its not the same error message, the context gets highlighted now: "cannot resolve construcor'ArrayAdapter(com...,int, java.util.List<java.lang.String>)'

and what's a diamond shorthand? :)

Comment: diamond operator (that `<>` part of `adapter` instantiation) is shorthand for generic class instantiation. But if you don't parametrized variable declaration (like you did with `adapter`), then you don't need diamond operator either. Type parameters will be defaulted to `Object`...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to pass a Context to the Constructor of ArrayAdapter. You're actually in initializing it in a Fragment class, so `this` is not valid as a Context. Try calling

```
final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                mutableBookings);
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the methods do not run directly in the activity and do not have access to it, not because of this, but because of the getApplicationContext ()

```
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mutableBookings);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using type in your `Adapter` declaring. You are missing the `type` of your `mutableBookings`:

```
final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mutableBookings);
```

Comment: (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mutableBookings); gets highlighted red now,     "cannot resolve construcor'ArrayAdapter(com...,int, java.util.List<java.lang.String>)'

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Fragment so you should use

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(**getContext()**,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
```

Comment: What's the meaning of **getContext()**?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as error: cannot infer type arguments for ArrayAdapter<> when I was using the code below:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayListward_items=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(wardItemsKisumuSeme));
ArrayAdapter<String> ward_itemsAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.style_spinner,arrayListward_items);
                    wardSpinner.setAdapter(ward_itemsAdapter);
```

I changed the this to getApplicationContext() and was able to fix the error, try that:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayListward_items=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(wardItemsKisumuSeme));
ArrayAdapter<String> ward_itemsAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.style_spinner,arrayListward_items);
                    wardSpinner.setAdapter(ward_itemsAdapter);
```