# Java - Change value of spinner by spinner

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a spinner (2) change its contents off of another spinner (1).

I am currently getting an error in the second spinners' array adapters ***"Error:(28, 57) error: cannot infer type arguments for ArrayAdapter<>"***

Here is my code:

```Java
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class DetailsForm extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details_form);

        final Spinner carBrand = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.carBrand);
        String[] items = new String[]{"Honda", "Nissan", "Toyota"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
        carBrand.setAdapter(adapter);
        carBrand.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            String carBrand = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if (carBrand.equals("Nissan")) {
                    final Spinner model = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.model);
                    String[] models = new String[]{"S14", "R34", "240SX"};
                    ArrayAdapter<String> modeladapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, models);
                    model.setAdapter(modeladapter);

                } else if (carBrand.equals("Honda")) {
                    Spinner model = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.model);
                    String[] models = new String[]{"Civic", "NSX", "Accord"};
                    ArrayAdapter<String> modeladapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, models);
                    model.setAdapter(modeladapter);
                } else if (carBrand.equals("Toyota")) {
                    Spinner model = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.model);
                    String[] models = new String[]{"Supra", "AE86", "GT86"};
                    ArrayAdapter<String> modeladapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, models);
                    model.setAdapter(modeladapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388547/cannot-infer-type-arguments-for-arrayadapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code

**From:**

```
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            String carBrand = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (carBrand.equals("Nissan")) {
                final Spinner model = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.model);
                String[] models = new String[]{"S14", "R34", "240SX"};
                ArrayAdapter<String> modeladapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, models);
                model.setAdapter(modeladapter);

            } else if (carBrand.equals("Honda")) {
                Spinner model = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.model);
                String[] models = new String[]{"Civic", "NSX", "Accord"};
                ArrayAdapter<String> modeladapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, models);
                model.setAdapter(modeladapter);
            } else if (carBrand.equals("Toyota")) {
                Spinner model = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.model);
                String[] models = new String[]{"Supra", "AE86", "GT86"};
                ArrayAdapter<String> modeladapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, models);
                model.setAdapter(modeladapter);
            }
        }
```

**To:**

```
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            String carBrand = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (carBrand.equals("Nissan")) {
                final Spinner model = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.model);
                String[] models = new String[]{"S14", "R34", "240SX"};
                ArrayAdapter<String> modeladapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(YourActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, models);
                model.setAdapter(modeladapter);

            } else if (carBrand.equals("Honda")) {
                Spinner model = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.model);
                String[] models = new String[]{"Civic", "NSX", "Accord"};
                ArrayAdapter<String> modeladapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(YourActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, models);
                model.setAdapter(modeladapter);
            } else if (carBrand.equals("Toyota")) {
                Spinner model = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.model);
                String[] models = new String[]{"Supra", "AE86", "GT86"};
                ArrayAdapter<String> modeladapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(YourActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, models);
                model.setAdapter(modeladapter);
            }
        }
```

`YourActivity` is your `activity` class name. This change is necessary because inside the `OnItemSelectedListener`, `this` represent object of listener which is different type than of `context`, you need object reference of `context` or `activity` to call `ArrayAdapter` constructor. This solution should work for you.

Comment: This solved my issue, thank you so much, I appreciate it greatly!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the context of the current activity. In this line change `this` to `DetailsForm.this:`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> modeladapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(DetailsForm.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, models);
```